# Factoring a morphism of schemes when the image is contained in an open subset

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a morphism of schemes. Suppose $f(X) \subseteq U$, where $U$ is an open subset of $Y$. Is it then the case that $f$ factors as $X \to U \to Y$, where $U \to Y$ is an open immersion? Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? 

Try defining $g : X \rightarrow U$ by having the same continuous function as $f$, and the pullback is the restriction of the one from $f$.

Comment: What do you mean by the restriction of the one from $f$ here? thank you

Comment: $f^\# :  O_Y \rightarrow f_* O_X$ is a collection of morphisms $O_Y(V) \rightarrow O_X(f^{-1}(V))$ for open subsets $V \subseteq X$.  If $g : X \rightarrow U$ is a morphism, then $g^\# : O_U(V) \rightarrow O_X(g^{-1}(V))$. From the condition that $f(X) \subseteq U$, we have that if $V \subseteq U$, then $O_X(g^{-1}(V)) = O_X(f^{-1}(V))$. Can you finish the proof from here?

Comment: We define $g = f$ for the map of the underlying topological spaces, and for open $V \subseteq U$, we can define $g^{\#}_V = f^{\#}_V$ because $O_{Y}(V) = O_U(V)$. Then $(f, f^{\#})$ factors through $(g, g^{\#})$. Thank you very much!

Comment: Should it be open subsets $V \subseteq Y$? and not $V \subseteq X$ in your second comment

Comment: Yes, my bad, that was a typo.